# MSP Install - Error 2920:  Source directory not specified for file

Tags: wix, windows-installer, msp

I have a base install which includes a file, then two patches after that which update that file. One patch has already been deployed, but I found out too late that [I should have set the SequenceStart](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/patch_building.htm) on the `<Family>` element in the patch declaration. Now when I look at the patch in Orca the new file has a Sequence of 2, which is the same as some existing file.

Now I've got another patch that I want to apply over this, but even when I set the new SequenceStart correctly, it will fail with this message:

```
MSI (s) (D8:EC) [15:46:34:054]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (D8:EC) [15:46:34:054]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (D8:EC) [15:46:34:054]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 MSI (s) (D8:EC) [15:46:34:054]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (D8:EC) [15:46:34:054]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 MSI (s) (D8:EC) [15:46:34:054]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (D8:EC) [15:46:34:054]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
DEBUG: Error 2920:  Source directory not specified for file <file ID>.
```

I have a feeling that the invalid sequence number on the first patch is messing things up here. Though the error only happens in Windows Server 2003. The second patch install succeeds in Server 2008.

Am I stuck here? Is the only way out to do a fresh install? Or could there be something else that's causing the error?

(edit) Tested it even with a correct intermediary Sequence number and it's still failing with the same error. So it must be something else. Does anyone have any clue?

(edit2) The error is thrown when using Windows Installer 3.1 but everything works when using Windows Installer 4.5.

Comment: Are you patching the binary or delivering the whole new file with the patch?

Comment: Whole new file with the patch. Though I've found out that all of our target machines will have Windows Installer 4.5 on them so I've stopped investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stopped investigating I won't comment much, just mention that I would test uninstall of all the different scenarios:

1: uninstall of original setup without patches
2: uninstall of patch 1
3: uninstall of patch 2
4: uninstall of whole product after patching with patch 1
5: uninstall of whole product after patching with patch 2

Patching is a world of pain...